# Sumatoria en Haskell

Tags: haskell

necesito hacer la sumatoria desde i = 1 hasta n de i^n en Haskell.
Alguien tiene idea o me puede ayudar a hacerlo?.. Estoy haciendo un proyecto y necesito eso en haskell que no tengo mucha idea.

Comment: `f n = [i^n | i <- [1..n]]` aproximable como `g n = (e / (e - 1)) * n**n` véase https://oeis.org/A031971

Comment: Nadie tiene la obligación de responderte así que es recomendable que seas un poco más humilde y no intentes meter prisas o lo más probable es que la gente pase de responderte.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no muestra ningún esfuerzo por parte del OP en lo que respecta a la solución del problema.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas noches, una posible solución es esta:

```
sumtoria i n | i==n = i**n
|otherwise = i**n + sumtoria (i+1) n
```

Cuando i=n hace la potencia, en los otros casos va acumulando las potencias mientras aumenta i. Sólo se contempla metiendo valores de i menores a n.
Una solución más elegante podría ser utilizando funciones de orden superior, pero eso ya es otro tema.

Answer (score 2):

La forma más simple:

```
sumatoria :: Integer -> Integer
sumatoria n = sum [ i^n | i <- [1..n]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenos dias una posible respuesta para tu problema seria

```
suma a b | a==b = a**b|otherwise = a**b + suma (a+1) b
```

Main

```
suma (2,3)
```

Espero te sirva